# WIll LINQ cache a value if a select for it presents twice?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `LINQ` query to a `DataTable`:

```
var list = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
group row by row.Field<byte>("ID") into g
select new
{
   ID = g.Key,
   Name = (from c in g
      select c.Field<string>("name")).First(),
   Localized = (from c in g
      select myDic[c.Field<string>("name"))].First();
};
```

where `ID` is a primary column, `Name` - data from query and `Localized` - a value from a dictionary where key - that data from query (`Name`).

Will `LINQ` cache that data from query for the second `select` or I have to do this in another way?

And another question: if I'll put dictionary creation in select, will it been crated every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ does not do any kind of query analysis/optimizations (see note below). Instead use the C# ["let" clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) (which maps to the [SelectMany method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)) to capture that value once for reuse in the select statement. Here is your revised query:

```
var list = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
group row by row.Field<byte>("ID") into g
let name = (from c in g
            select c.Field<string>("name")).First()
select new
{   
    ID = g.Key,   
    Name = name,
    Localized = myDic[name]
};
```

**NOTE:** IQueryable providers can technically translate LINQ expressions into more optimal ones if they wanted to, but that's a subject of another discussion and you're using pure "LINQ to Objects" here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not cache data.  Therefore, it will perform the dictionary lookup for every element of every group.